# replace jsonArray with custom name wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have response data and it contains an array named JsonArray and I want to change it with a custom name how?

see the response below :

```xml
<jsonArray>
    <jsonElement>
        <Title></Title>
        <Address1></Address1>
        <Address2></Address2>
        <Street></Street>
        <District></District>
        <City></City>
        <PostCode></PostCode>
        <AdditionalNumber></AdditionalNumber>
        <RegionName></RegionName>
        <UnitNumber></UnitNumber>
        <Latitude></Latitude>
        <Longitude></Longitude>
    </jsonElement>
    <jsonElement>
        <Title></Title>
        <Address1></Address1>
        <Address2></Address2>
        <Street></Street>
        <District></District>
        <City></City>
        <PostCode></PostCode>
        <AdditionalNumber></AdditionalNumber>
        <RegionName></RegionName>
        <UnitNumber>8</UnitNumber>
        <Latitude></Latitude>
        <Longitude></Longitude>  
    </jsonElement>
</jsonArray>
```

can I do it with Enrich?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an XML as the response you can't use the EnrichMediator's key replacement feature here. It only supports JSON key replacements. So you can do something like the below with the `PayloadFactory Mediator`.

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <newJsonArray>$1</newJsonArray>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//jsonElement"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

**Result**

```xml
<newJsonArray xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <jsonElement>
        <Title/>
        <Address1/>
        <Address2/>
        <Street/>
        <District/>
        <City/>
        <PostCode/>
        <AdditionalNumber/>
        <RegionName/>
        <UnitNumber/>
        <Latitude/>
        <Longitude/>
    </jsonElement>
    <jsonElement>
        <Title/>
        <Address1/>
        <Address2/>
        <Street/>
        <District/>
        <City/>
        <PostCode/>
        <AdditionalNumber/>
        <RegionName/>
        <UnitNumber>8</UnitNumber>
        <Latitude/>
        <Longitude/>
    </jsonElement>
</newJsonArray>
```

Comment: But also i want to rename jsonElement with a diffrent name

Comment: @SulaimanSadoon in that case, there is additional work, You may have to use XSLT mediator or simply Foreach mediator and then change the keys. Let me know if you can't figure it out. I can give a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use enrich mediator as follows.

Replace the KEY_NAME with any preferred name.

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" type="inline"> KEY_NAME </source>
    <target xpath="json-eval($.jsonArray)" action="replace" type="key"/>
</enrich>
```

For more details, please refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/enrich-mediator/#example-8-updating-the-key-name-of-an-existing-object

Comment: Thank you for your help , it's keep showing error when i adeed type="key" .